# Efficiently calculate mean within specified bins of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array (p) that represents the evolution of some prices. Additionally I have another numpy array (bins) of the same length that assigns each entry of p to a specific bin starting from 0. The goal is to calculate the mean of prices within each bin and return them in an array p_mean. This can be done by using a for loop like this:

```
p = np.array([100, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 103, 102, 103, 100, 105])
bins = np.array([3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9])
lengthBins = 10
p_mean = np.empty(lengthBins)
p_mean.fill(np.nan)
for i in range(lengthBins):
    p_mean[i] = p[bins==i].mean()

p_mean // Output: array([nan, nan, nan, 100.33, nan, 102., 104.33, 102.67, 100., 105.]
```

This gives the desired output (including the nans), however I feel there must be a faster way of doing this using numpy without using the for loop.

Comment: `np.bincount(bins,p,lengthBins)/np.bincount(bins,None,lengthBins)`

Comment: Thanks, that achieves exactly what I wanted and is a lot faster!